# When joining 2 tables and say table.column1<>table2.column it gives me multiple records and not the not equal to records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 table with employee id in both the table

```
select a.c1
from employee a 
join employee1 b on a.c1 <> b.c1
```

This one gives one to many records instead of not equal to records.

I have been using SQL Sever for the first time. This query will work on IBM DB2, not sure why it does not work in SQL Server

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

In any database, this query does the same thing.  You can understand this better if you do:

```
select a.c1, b.c1
from employee a cross join
     employee1 b
where a.c1 <> b.c1 ;
```

That is, it returns every pair of `c1` values from the two tables that are not equal.  It is a subquery of the Cartesian product.

I am guessing that you want `c1` values in the first table that are not in the second.  For this, `not exists` is a very reasonable approach:

```
select e.c1
from employee e
where not exists (select 1 from employee1 e1 where e1.c1 = e.c1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just trying to get employees in table A that are not in table B.

```
select c1 from employee where c1 not in (select c1 from employee1)
```